# LUA: does data lookup occur at the localized _G variable on the stack?

Tags: lua

My apologies if the title to this question is a bit confusing. I could not find a better way to describe my question. I have always bashed my head against to wall to figure out this specific situation in lua.

Given the example below, will lua look for the function inside the localized variable on the stack or look for it in the hash part of the table? Take note that the global function is written as `SomeGlobalFunc()` instead of `_G.SomeGlobalFunc()`

```
--localize the global environment
local _G = _G

--run global func
SomeGlobalFunc()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lua manual says:

> `_G` is never used internally, so changing its value will affect only your own code

This means all operations with `_G` do not affect Lua program behavior, except when you use this variable explicitly, such as `_G.func()`

In other words, Lua knowns where the globals table is located without accessing variable `_G`

P.S.
Lua uses internally `_ENV` variable, not `_G`

Comment: P.S. Most Programs using/supporting Lua 5.1 (Wireshark, VLC, LÖVE, e.t.c.) where no ```_ENV``` exists. But ```_G``` is present in ```package.loaded._G```. So ```_G``` is free for holding own table (```_G = {}```) with definitions of functions and methods or data. It can always be restored with: ```_G = require('_G')``` - Also whats requireable can instantly used with: ```print(require('_G')._VERSION)``` for example. In this case require references: ```package.loaded._G._VERSION```

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi - `_G = {}` - What overwriting `_G` may be useful for?  If you need a global table you can choose any name, `_G` does not have any benefit.